# При обращении к корню сайта происходит нежелательное перенаправление

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Имеется такое правило

```
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9\-/]+)?$ /system/modules/user.php?login=$1&%{QUERY_STRING} [PT,L]
```

Но при входе на `сайт.ру` отображается значение `system/modules/user.php?login=$1`
Если сайт открыть так `сайт.ру/index.php` то всё нормально. Нужно получать страницы вида `сайт.ру/логин` Как можно исправить?

Comment: Знак вопроса и слеш `/` уберите из `^([a-z0-9\-/]+)?$`.

Comment: Спасибо за помощь ^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вопрос задан очень туманно, два раза прочитал, слобо понял.
Приведенное вами регулярное выражение в правиле криво написано. Скорее всего для вашего случая, оно должно выглядеть вот так:

```
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9\-]+)$ /system/modules/user.php?login=$1&%{QUERY_STRING} [PT,L]
```

Тогда все ссылки вида `site.ru/world132` (world123 состоит из прописных анлийских букв, цифр или тире) будут переадресовываться на `/system/modules/user.php?login=world123`
Если у вас есть русские ники, то по идее нужно написать так (правда не проверял работу с русскими регулярными выражениями в `.htaccess`)

```
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9а-яё\-]+)$ /system/modules/user.php?login=$1&%{QUERY_STRING} [PT,L]
```

Comment: буковку `ё` забыли

Comment: Да не будут работать русские буквы в этом правиле.

Comment: Русские и ненужны.

Comment: @Visman кстати да, здесь уже буду кодированные ведь символы?

Comment: @korytoff, упс. Поспешил с комментарием. Если сайт в UTF-8 работает и .htaccess сохранить в UTF-8, то правило работать будет с русскими буквами.

Comment: @Visman да, но регулярка в любом случае не правильная

Comment: @korytoff почему не правильная? Из-за ё?

Comment: @alff0x1f да, и еще если мой ник будет user_777 ?

Comment: @korytoff Ну по поводу нижнего подчеркивания топикстартер ничего не говорил

Comment: Нижнее подчеркивание не помешало бы. 
И всё в UTF-8.

И с русскими символами ваша регулярка работает.